# What plugin provides the subtab feature in NvChad?

Tags: nvchad

There are the normal Neovim tabs but also some small tabs but I have hard time configuring the behavior of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they are controlled via the `tabline` option.

In NvChad the option is set the the callback `tabbufline` from the [nvchad_ui](https://github.com/NvChad/ui) plugin.

The NvChad documentation has a special [paragraph](https://nvchad.com/config/nvchad_ui#statusline--tabufline) to document what can be done on tabline